# Tool for measuring readability of English text

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation, language-support

Is there a command line program that takes a file containing English text, analyzes the text, and outputs its readability scores?

For example, if one feeds the program a text, the program should output the Flesch-Kincaid grade level, McLaughlin's SMOG grading, etc.

I believe such a program exists in the official repositories, but I cannot remember its name. There's also the possibility that I am misremebering.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [`diction` [image: Install diction]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/diction) package contains a tool called `style`:

> `Style`  analyses the surface characteristics of the writing style of a
>   document.  It prints
>          various readability grades, length of words, sentences and  paragraphs.   It  can  further
>          locate  sentences  with  certain  characteristics.

For example, if I evaluate your question body (saved in a file `flux_question`) to print the sentences with a readability index (ARI) over 10:

```
$ style -r 10 flux_question
flux_question:1: Is there a command line program that takes a file containing English text, analyzes the text, and outputs its readability scores?
flux_question:2: For example, if one feeds the program a text, the program should output the Flesch-Kincaid grade level, McLaughlin's SMOG grading, etc.
readability grades:
        Kincaid: 10.2
        ARI: 10.8
        Coleman-Liau: 12.5
        Flesch Index: 51.1/100
        Fog Index: 12.0
        Lix: 48.6 = school year 9
        SMOG-Grading: 11.2
sentence info:
        333 characters
        65 words, average length 5.12 characters = 1.65 syllables
        4 sentences, average length 16.2 words
        25% (1) short sentences (at most 11 words)
        0% (0) long sentences (at least 26 words)
        1 paragraphs, average length 4.0 sentences
        25% (1) questions
        25% (1) passive sentences
        longest sent 21 wds at sent 2; shortest sent 8 wds at sent 4
word usage:
        verb types:
        to be (1) auxiliary (2) 
        types as % of total:
        conjunctions 5% (3) pronouns 9% (6) prepositions 2% (1)
        nominalizations 0% (0)
sentence beginnings:
        pronoun (1) interrogative pronoun (0) article (0)
        subordinating conjunction (0) conjunction (0) preposition (0)
```

To filter the output you can use e.g. `tail -n8` to get only the grades or `grep 'Flesch\|SMOG'` to just print the Flesch Index and the SMOG-Grading:

```
$ style flux_question | grep 'Flesch\|SMOG'
        Flesch Index: 51.7/100
        SMOG-Grading: 11.2
```

#### Further reading

- [`man style`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/style.1.html)
- [linux.com article: Improve your writing with the GNU style checkers](https://www.linux.com/news/improve-your-writing-gnu-style-checkers)